# Freenom.com and AWS Amplify: Amazon asks me to 'configure root domain' (@ ANAME abc-whatever-xyz.cloudfront.net) -> Freenom: wild cards not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname, domain-name, aws-amplify

I am trying to use a custom domain name on AWS Amplify.

Step 2 in the process is:

> **2. Configure root domain** In order to use your root domain you must configure an ANAME record (also called an ALIAS) in your DNS provider.
> If your DNS provider does not support ANAME/ALIAS, migrate your zone
> file to Amazon Route53. Learn more If you are migrating a custom
> domain that is already serving production traffic, please wait until
> your new application loads successfully at the .cloudfront.net url
> shown below before updating your DNS records:

The values I need to plug in are:

```
@
ANAME
abc-whatever-xyz.cloudfront.net
```

Please note that Freenom does not have a type called "ANAME". However, there is "A" as well as "AAAA". If I use the "A", and plug in the values I receive the following warning:

> Error occured: Wild cards are not allowed!

What should I do please?

Comment: Root domain is the naked domain `yourdomain.com`.

Comment: @hephalump Yes, how do I fix this? Currently, the `yourdomain.com` does not load at all, but the `www.yourdomain.com` loads perfectly. I guess since I was able to add the WWW cname, but how do I get `yourdomain.com` also accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your AWS Amplify app available under https://your-domain.org you need to create an **A** record, more specifically an **ANAME / ALIAS** record. You can transfer your host zone to AWS Route 53 as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html if your DNS Service does not support ANAME / ALIAS records.

After you have switched your DNS Service to AWS Route 53 and the AWS name servers are in use you need to add the ANAME / ALIAS record. I found that the most straightforward way to do so is via the AWS Amplify console. Go to your app and then to **Domain management**. If you haven't already setup up a domain for your AWS Amplify app, follow the guide here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-domains.html. Click on **Manage Subdomains** and for your root domain (i.e. https://your-domain.org) click *disable* on the right. The domain status in the AWS Amplify console will say *Available (with blue dots)*. Wait until the status changes into a green checkmark. Click again on *Manage Subdomains* and enable the root domain again. Wait until the status changes again into a green checkmark.

Go to the AWS Route 53 host zone. A new record

*your-domain.org    A   xxxxx.cloudfront.net.*

was added which is the ANAME / ALIAS record for your root domain to point to the AWS Amplify app at xxxxx.cloudfront.net.