# Can't add AWS amplify ANAME to freenom domain DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add my custom domain from freenom to my AWS amplify app. The AWS suggests that I have to add an ANAME record (which I read is just called A on freenom) for the target: 123example456.cloudfront.net. When I try to add that url to my freenom target I get the error:

> Error occured: Invalid value in dnsrecord

Also, AWS's instructions say:

> If you are migrating a custom domain that is already serving
> production traffic, please wait until your new application loads
> successfully at the .cloudfront.net url shown below before
> updating your DNS records:

Thus far the .cloudfront.net address gives a 404, I guess it might take some time for it to start working, but am not sure if it is longer than what has passed thus far (about 2 hours or something).

I've managed to get the url with www to work by using CNAME, using the amplify app url, as in:

```
www CNAME master.d2cnacuo0erb7y.amplifyapp.com
```

but this also doesn't work for ANAME, so I can't get the domain without www to work. When I add the cloudfront url to the CNAME freenom allows it, but it gives the 404, while for the ANAME record it gives that error when I try to add it.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379231/freenom-com-and-aws-amplify-amazon-asks-me-to-configure-root-domain-aname) question, but the only answer provided involves Route 53, I had Route 53 setup and working but decided to remove it because I was being charged for it.

Why can't I add the url to the A record on Freenom?

Answer (score 2):

“A” records (ie alias) only support IP addresses as values.  That is why you are getting an error.  CNAME is the record type you want when you want a URL as a value.

Route53 is a special case and since Cloudfront and Route53 are both AWS products they have special integrations that will allow you to create an A record for cloudfront resources identified by a url.  Behind the scenes, Route53 gets the IP from cloudfront and will update the A record when/if the IP changes.    AWS doesn’t expose this functionality for other DNS providers (ie freenom)

Comment: I see. But isn't there another way then to allow people to reach my website using the domain name without www?

Comment: Also, are you sure about that? Because AWS in it's instructions gives a url for me to input on ANAME for my domain provider. Why would they do this if it can only take IPs?

Comment: If you want the cloudfront to map to your website root without the www, then create the cname record on the root of your domain instead of www.   Can you link to the document that references the a record?

Comment: How can I create it on the root? Freenom does not allow the field to be left empty, nor @ which is what AWS suggests. It also doesn't accept my full domain.

Comment: I read that instruction when going into my Amplify project, click in "Action" -> "Update DNS Records", it instructs me to fill a record with @ ANAME <id>.cloudfront.net

Comment: I am having a similar issue - if I add a @ CNAME record for the cloudfront URL that is stated in the "Update DNS records" window, I stop receiving emails into  my domain associated workspace but using domain URL without www seems to work - very confusing - do you guys have any updates on this? @ThiagoPereiraMaia

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience. The instructions on the dns records pop-up are ambiguous.

Your amplify app will never load on the .cloudfront.net url. AWS only uses it to set up a cloudfront distribution for your site.
Just do the CNAME and the AAA records. Once the records complete propagation, your site will be up on the custom domain name.

Comment: How to you set up AAAA records? There is no IP address let alone IPv6 in cloudfront